# Regex - Matching Strings with a Single Character

Tags: regex

I'm fairly new to regex. I'm looking for an expression which will return results which meet the following criteria:

- The First word must be 3 letters or more
- The last word must be 3 characters or more
- If any word or words in-between the first and last word contains ONLY 1 letter, then return that phrase
- Every other word in-between the first and last character that (apart from the single letter words) must be 3 letters or more

I would like it to return phrases like:

'Therefore **a** hurricane shall arrive' and 'However **I** know **I** like Michael Smith'

There should be a space between each word.

So far I have:

```
^([A-Za-z]{3,})*$( [A-Za-z])*$( [A-Za-z]{3,})*$
```

Any help would be appreciated. Is it something to do with the spacing? I'm using an application called 'Oracle EDQ'.

Comment: What about the previous question? Was any answer useful? Did either of them work for you?

Comment: your answer was spot on - thank you. any help with this one would be appreciated :)

Comment: I do not know how to help with this one since the Oracle EDQ syntax does not support word boundaries. anubhava's regex won't work without them.

Comment: Maybe `^[a-zA-Z]{3,}(\s+|(?!\S)([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]{3,})\s)*\s*[a-zA-Z]{3,}$`?

Comment: I found the `(?!pattern1)pattern2` on the documentation page, looks rather nasty for those who are accustomed to other regex flavors

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: unfortunately the operation timed out, it was taking a long time to execute. i was running the regex over 160,000 rows

Comment: Alright, but perhaps, `^[a-zA-Z]{3,}(\s+|([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]{3,})\s)*\s*[a-zA-Z]{3,}$` will work? Just without `(?!\S)`.

Comment: yes I believe it would work- thanks again for your help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a normal regex world you'd use a `\b`, a word boundary.

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3,}(\s+|\b([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]{3,})\b)*\s+[a-zA-Z]{3,}$
                  ^^                       ^^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hA8mV2/4)

And perhaps, non-capturing groups (as anubhava shows).

From what I see, there are no word boundaries in Oracle EDQ regex syntax (as well as non-capturing groups). You should rely on the `\s` pattern, matching whitespace.

So, make it obligatory, either with

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3,}(\s+|\s([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]{3,}))*\s+[a-zA-Z]{3,}$
                  ^^
```

OR

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3,}(\s+|([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]{3,})\s)*\s*[a-zA-Z]{3,}$
                                         ^^    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3,}(?:\s+|(?:[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]{3,}))*\s+[a-zA-Z]{3,}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hA8mV2/3)